# rule exclusion in flex

Tags: flex-lexer

I am trying to write a flex file which recognizes `(-! comment !-)` as one token called `comment`. The following is my file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

void showToken(char* name);
void error();
void enter();

int lineNum=1;
%}

%option yylineno
%option noyywrap

whitespace  ([\t ])
enter       ([\n])
startcomment (\(\-\!)
endcomment (\!\-\))
comment (^\!\-\))

%%

{startcomment}{comment}*{endcomment} showToken("COMMENT");
{enter} enter();
{whitespace}
.   error();

%%

void showToken(char* name){
    printf("%d %s %s %d% \n",lineNum,name, yytext); 
}

void enter(){
    lineNum++;
}

void error(){
printf("%d error %s \n",lineNum,yytext);
}
```

but i fail for a simple `(-! comment !-)` input, this file does recognize the `(-!` and `!-)` but fails to recognize my `comment` rule. I did try replacing it with `comment (^{endcomment})` but it did not work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that `^` means the following pattern should not match, but it means to match the start of a line. Inside a character class `^` does mean everything but the character class, but outside a character class its meaning is totally different.

In answer to your question for an alternative. Your problem is similar to C-comment `/* comment */`. The following expression matches C-comment:

```
"/*"([^*]|"*"+[^/*])*"*"+"/"
```

Alternatively and more intuitive (if you like) you can use a sub-automaton:

```
%x comment
%%
"/*"              { BEGIN(comment); }
<comment>(.|"\n") { /* Skip */ }
<comment>"*/"     { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
%%
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to apply this to your comment style. Having `!-)` as the closing of your comment, makes the first solution a bit more complicated.

Note that in general the second solution is preferred because it does not cause the use of a big buffer. The first solution will create a buffer containing the complete comment (which can be big), whereas the buffer requirements for the second solution is at most two characters long.

The easiest way to maintain line-numbers is using the `%option yylineno` as `flex` will then keep track of line-numbers in the variable `int yylineno`. Alternatively you can count the number of new-lines in `yytext`. In the second solution you can split the second rule and make a separate case for `"\n"` and count line-numbers there.

Comment: Thank you for your responce, now i have two problems:

If i use the first method suggested i am unable to increase the line number "lineNum" (some int i defined) when getting to \n in the comment which is something i am required to do.

If i use the second method i am unable to use yytext, and since i have no bound to the length of a comment i can not use buffers and pointers.